# Pin Mapped Wemos D1 R1

Tags: sensors, pins

I want to ask about Wemos d1 R1. Can I use those pins connected for different sensor?

For example I use pin D5 and D13 for switch and push button, or I use pin D7 and D11 for two different sensors.

Thanks.

Comment: well, D7 and D11 seem to be the same physical GPIO on the ESP8266, so, no, you probably can't use D7 and D11 for two different sensors

Comment: I need 13 pins for sensors and actuators. I use wemos d1 R1 because the actuators have to be controlled by telegram. So, any idea what I have to do if I can't use some pins for two different sensors?

Comment: esp8266 only ever has about 8 pins you can use

Comment: 8 pins or 11 pins?

Comment: Available GPIO pins are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 - so, yeah, 11, sorry (forgot to include Tx and Rx and GPIO16 - I never use those for obvious reasons) - note: I'm talking about GPIO pins, not the `Dn` pins, as you can see, D5 and D13 **refer to a single GPIO (14)** - in fact D11,D12,D13,D14, D15 are dupes of D7,D6,D5,D4,D5 respectively

Comment: depending on the type of sensor, however, you may have enough pins (e.g. you can, and do, put multiple DS18B20 temperature probes on one pin) - without knowing your full requirements, I'm guessing

Comment: the pinout of D1 R1 is unfortunate. R2 has it much better

Comment: I didn't know you could still send telegrams...

Comment: What do u mean? I will use all of pins to sensors and actuators (11pins). Could I still connect to telegram?

Comment: can i use TX pin to connect with sensor?

Comment: I would not recommend using TX as input. It outputs boot log at startup.